# Catch Exception class in Kotlin good practice?

Tags: exception, kotlin

Kotlin doesn't have checked exceptions. Would it be bad practice to catch the class `Exception` in Kotlin code? In Java this would be a no go.

Are there other ways than relying on the api docs of the function you are calling to handle exceptions the right way?

```
fun beSave() {
    try {
        // some blackbox code
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        // handler
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a matter of personal opinion, and that's mine: you may not want to catch that exception at that level and let the exception propagate on the stacktrace and so that's why we dont' have checked exception. And so yes, you have to relay on the docs of the function and remember to handle the exception where you really need.
Back then I read this article on the topic. It may be useful for you too, says the same i think but better https://phauer.com/2015/checked-exceptions-are-evil/

Comment: just checked on the intellij plugin marketplace and there is one plugin that could help. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12673-csense--kotlin-checked-exceptions
Did not tried myself but it could be useful

Comment: Bear in mind that apart from not giving an error if you fail to catch or declare exceptions, Kotlin treats exceptions just like Java.